# Api request JSON slow preformance

Tags: php, json, api

Hi I'm calling a api for a species database called encyclopedia of life. I initially call a method called search, which renders 30 results (I call that method like the one below), but then for the 30 results I call this method that gives me info for each of the results, so I basically call this method for 30 results and its very slow. What suggestions do you have to make these api calls faster? thank you

```
$jsonurls = 'http://eol.org/api/pages/1.0/'.$id.'.json?images=2&videos=0&sounds=0&maps=0&text=2&iucn=false&subjects=overview&licenses=all&details=true&common_names=true&synonyms=true&references=true';
$jsons = file_get_contents($jsonurls,0,null,null);
$responsetaxObjects = json_decode($jsons);

//then I run through the object array like this

foreach($responsetaxObjects->taxonConcepts as $sources){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying the header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

? That will return the results in compressed form, which may save you some wire time. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like their API provides a way to get full details for all search results, so you look to be out of luck in terms of reducing the number of round trips over the wire. They also have a cache setting you can play with if you're going to wind up GETing the same pages multiple times.